# Data validation in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008. The job of this stored procedure is very simple - it inserts data in a table. One of the column in that table is of varchar type and I have issue with that column's data validation. It is accepting any value client code is passing into- this is expected to happen. I was told not to insert 'NEW'  into that column. Client code is mysteriously sending 'NEW' as stored procedure parameter, stored procedure is inserting that value as it is. I understand that this needs to handled by client code. But , as I am responsible for the table data - I am planning to throw exception when stored procedure will find 'NEW'. How can I achieve this ?

This is format of my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Object_Save
    @Id int = 0 OUTPUT              
    ,@OrderId int
    ,@OrderNumber varchar(20)
AS
    BEGIN TRY
        IF @Id = 0
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Table_Order(OrderId, OrderNumber) 
                VALUES (@OrderID, @OrderNumber)

                Set @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                -- Update
            END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        exec error_catch
    END CATCH
```

Comment: Also have you considered cleaning up the invalid data and sticking a check constraint on the column itself?

Comment: I considered about constraint but my manager won't allow deleting any records. We have this flag 'Deleted' that keeps track of active / inactive records. No deletion is permitted once inserted.

Comment: Are you literally saying you want to not insert the word 'NEW'?  Do you want to strip it out or fail?

Comment: to which parameter clients are passing the value "New" ???

Comment: @MuhammedAli - By process of elimination the parameter that isn't an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you can do something like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Object_Save
    @Id int = 0 OUTPUT              
    ,@OrderId int
    ,@OrderNumber varchar(20)
AS
    BEGIN TRY
        IF @Id = 0
            BEGIN
        /*Say clients been passing value "New" to @OrderNumber*/

           IF (@OrderNumber = 'New')
            BEGIN
              RAISERROR('Invalid OrderNumber Please Provide valid value', 16, 1)
              RETURN
            END

                INSERT INTO Table_Order(OrderId, OrderNumber) 
                VALUES (@OrderID, @OrderNumber)

                Set @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                -- Update
            END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        exec error_catch
    END CATCH
```

Comment: If you wrap a RAISERROR in a TRY ... CATCH, wouldn't it wind up catching the exception you just raised?

Comment: I checked the variable value if its "New" than raised error which will cause the code to jump into catch block, Return key word will stop the further execution of code.

Comment: Since your RETURN statement is after the point where the code raises the error and control moves to the CATCH block, I don't think your RETURN statement will get executed.  (Though, if the END CATCH is the end of the procedure, the effect is the same.)

Comment: @AnnL. Just checked it and yes you are right thank you for the Tip much appreciated, I guess it has become more of a habit now of making sure proc returns lol. anyway thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: a lot of procedures where I havent used try catch block it is mandatory there but not in this case, like I said its more of habit now.